# Creating history or log for certain events

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, history

I am not sure what is better perfomance whise so I ask you guys.

The problem is following:

I have a system where each User gets a certain amount of credit for certain events. So I gave my User an attribute named creditscore that gets altered on those events. Everything works well. But now I want the user to actually see what he did when and how much credit he got for this.

What would be better here:

- Saving the whole history in a text attribute and add lines for each event

  or
- writing an extra model associated with the user and create an instance for every event.
  or

  or
- something way different?

Since there are several events per user per day it would be either a huge text or a huge amount of instances. What would be better looking at website performance.

Comment: id recommend using a model associated to the event and the user so that you can track the actions and also what each action is worth credit wise. It will be easier to query in the long run that way.

Comment: Additionally, with proper indexing, you should not experience any performance issues with the model approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You absolutely do NOT want to store the history in a text attribute. Management of this will be a nightmare as will querying the data.

You could create a CreditEvent model and store the individual events in there.  That would work fine.

However, before you start, check rubygems.org and ruby-toolbox.com to see if someone has already done the hard work.  I know of at least one gem that seems to do exactly what you want to do:

https://github.com/merit-gem/merit

Comment: Thanks that answers my question perfectly. I wont use merit though because I think it adds way more complexity than I need and I like to keep it as simply as possible to better oversee security risks. Went now with a model associated to the User model that gets created on every event and saves needed information. Now I will work on an approach to autodelete the new model instances after a certain period to keep everything lean.